# Adding googleTranslateElementInit to an existing website (not my own site)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, tags, google-translate

I want to translate a page through a google chrome extension and I'm trying to add this function googleTranslateElementInit on another site using right-click mouse "translate this page" on a Chinese website but it doesn't work, i don't get what am I missing and how to fix the code in order for the site to change it language to english using this function.

---

The code works when i try to run it with my own html page
but when I try to add all the codes needed for the function to work
it seems like it doesn't do anything...

---

Do I need to add additional settings on manifest.json for MAC pcs?

```
const root = document.querySelector('body');
root.setAttribute("id", "google_translate_element");

$('<script type="text/javascript">' +
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement(
                    {
                        pageLanguage: 'zh-CN',
                        includedLanguages: 'en',
                        gaTrack: true,
                        gaId: 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'
                    },
                    'google_translate_element'
                );
            } + '</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);

$('<script  type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body)[0];
```

I expect to have the text translated as it worked with my own html file
but all i get is the added function and scripts to the head and body sections and nothing happens.
thanks for your help in advanced...

Comment: Try specifying the URL scheme too: `src="https://translate.google.com..............`

Comment: @wOxxOm can you elaborate more? I don't quite sure what do you mean

Comment: Look at the last line in your code.